# Calculating percentage change over a range of 5 cells where a different two will be populated on each row

Tags: excel

I have 5 columns for 5 consecutive years. I need to calculate the percentage change between the first value present across the column range and the second value present. The other three columns will be blank. In the attached picture Z2 would calculate the percentage change for **V**2 to **Y**2 but for Z4 it would calculate the percentage change between **U**4 and **Y**4

[Column Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h5ln.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Z2** enter the **Array Formula**:

```
=(-INDEX(U2:Y2,MATCH(TRUE,U2:Y2<>0,0))+LOOKUP(2,1/(U2:Y2>0),U2:Y2))/INDEX(U2:Y2,MATCH(TRUE,U2:Y2<>0,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You can use a *MUCH* simpler formula if the %-change is never negative!